# TypeError: _jquery2.default.ajax is not a function

Tags: javascript, express, typeerror

```
TypeError: _jquery2.default.ajax is not a function
at Object.login (/Users/Vinit/Documents/Bookr/src/util/uber/auth_api.js:19:12)
at /Users/Vinit/Documents/Bookr/server.js:22:21
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/Vinit/Documents/Bookr/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/Vinit/Documents/Bookr/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/Vinit/Documents/Bookr/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/Vinit/Documents/Bookr/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/Vinit/Documents/Bookr/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (/Users/Vinit/Documents/Bookr/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/Users/Vinit/Documents/Bookr/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at /Users/Vinit/Documents/Bookr/server.js:14:3
```

This is the error I'm receiving. I'm trying to user uber's api and I have received an authorization code but need to make a post request to exchange it for an access token. Here is my server code:

```
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "http://localhost:3000");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});

app.use('/app', express.static(path.join(__dirname, './app')));

app.get('/auth', (req, res) => {
  res.json(UberAuth.login(req.query.code));
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server started on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

The problem is is in the app.get('/auth' ....) portion. For some reason< when I try to call the 'login' function I defined:

```
export const login = (authCode) => {
  console.log(authCode);
  return $.ajax({
    url: "https://login.uber.com/v2/token",
    method: "POST",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
      client_id: UBER_CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: UBER_CLIENT_SECRET,
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
      code: authCode,
      scope: 'profile'
    }
  });
};
```

I really don't understand why I'm getting this error because everywhere else in my program, jquery works fine. I've tried alot of things and can't figure it out. I'm new to express, I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not properly importing jQuery to use at the login function. Make sure the `$` variable has the ajax function at this point.

Comment: It is imported at the top of the file just like I imported it everywhere else in my project as well.